# iTextSharp HTML to PDF - Handling images

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to take a html file and convert it to PDF however i'm having an issue where i need it to realise when it hits and image and take the image from the HTML and insert it in the correct spot in the PDF.

All the HTML files are basic HTML files in a simple format that generally follows:

Text

Image

Text

Image.

Answer (score 2):

Probably iTextSharp's XML Worker cannot retrieve the image files.  Two cases:

1. The images have to be retrieved over a network connection, e.g. the `src` of your `img` tag is `http://...`. In this case, failure of retrieving the images can be because the machine that runs the iTextSharp process cannot reach the server that hosts the images.  The server could be down, the machine could be behind a web proxy or a firewall, the machine is not connected to the internet, etc.
2. The images have to be retrieved from the local file system.  In this case you likely need an `ImageProvider` to point to the correct location.  Have a look at [this example that demonstrates the issue](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/D08_ParseHtmlImagesLinksOops).  Here's [an example that fixes this using an `ImageProvider`](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/D09_ParseHtmlImagesLinks)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The images and the HTML files are on my local machine not on a server anywhere. I'm using a HTMLWorker to parse through the HTML and it works fine without images. However as soon as it involves images it can't get past the IMG tag. I was wondering if there is a way to detect that it reaches the IMG tag. Process the image and insert it into the pdf where it should go and then carry on with the text.

Comment: `HTMLWorker` is deprecated. Have a look at `XMLWorker` instead. The examples I linked to in my answer show how to use `XMLWorker`.

Comment: Unfortunately I've inherited legacy code and just need to get it working with images. It works fine with text but we now need it to function with images. So don't really want to change over to XMLWorker.

Comment: Helpful answer! My stack included logic: Spring Controller -> ServiceImpl (generate logic) -> Velocity (generate template) -> iText use template to generate PDF which has images. I had specified http:// in my Velocity template and iText was unable to hit the http:// server. I wrote ImageProvider for iText to specify a root path for images present in Velocity Template and finally it got working.